# Create table DDL does not work when I use curly brackets instead of parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

The error message

> (ORA-00922: missing or invalid option)

appears when I try to run this code in Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE products {   
   product_id number not null,  
   name varchar(50),   
   product_cost number(5,2),   
   product_retail number(5,2),   
   product_type varchar(10),   
   store_id number not null,   
CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id) }
```

Comment: The SQL syntax calls for parentheses.  Of course, you get a syntax error if you don't follow the syntax.  Based on your title, it seems like you understand this.

Comment: So why do you try to use those invalid curly braces if you already know they are wrong?

Comment: Maybe for the same reason I watch the "Titanic" over and over again, hoping that **this time** Jack won't drown and that he and Rose will live happily ever after. So - even if curly brackets didn't work yesterday nor today morning, *maybe* they'll work today afternoon, just if you're patient enough. Just kidding, of course.

Comment: hey guys/girls, don't judge the OP by their newly edited question title, which was changed after they got the answer they needed.

Comment: @DuncanMoody, for future reference: when asking a question like this, it may help to indicate *why* you believed your syntax was correct (e.g. point to some poorly-written documentation, or perhaps you found the syntax example in a book somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `{}` to `()`:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
product_id number not null,
name varchar2(50),   -- varchar2
product_cost number(5,2),
product_retail number(5,2),
product_type varchar2(10),
store_id number not null,
CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id) );
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c14e9701c712154d89b27901b5b759b8)**

Comment: OmG that was so easy thank you.